# Show $\mathrm{Var} \big( c_1 X + c_2 Y + c_3 XY + c_4 X^2 + c_5 Y^2 \big) > 0$ for any not all zero $c_i$ where $(X, Y) \sim Normal$

Tags: probability, random-variables, partial-derivative

I would like to show the following

> For $(X, Y) \sim Normal \big( (\mu_1, \mu_2), \Sigma \big) $,
>   $$
> \mathrm{Var} \big( c_1 X + c_2 Y + c_3 XY + c_4 X^2 + c_5 Y^2 \big) > 0
> $$
>   for any, not all zero, constant $c_1, \cdots, c_5 \in \mathbb{R}$

**My attempt**

the statement seems equivalent to the following,

$$
c_1 x + c_2y + c_3(xy) + c_4 x^2 + c_5 y^2 = a \Rightarrow \exists! \ \ c_1 = \cdots = c_5 =0
$$

for some constant $a$ and "variables" $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

It seems too simple, because, by defining $(RHS) = f(x,y)$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y) &= c_1 + c_3 y + 2c_4 x = 0 \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} f(x,y) &= 2c_4 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y \partial x} f(x,y) &= c_3 = 0 \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) &= c_2 + c_3x + 2c_5y = 0 \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} f(x,y) &= 2c_5 = 0 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

so I got $c_1 = \cdots = c_5 = 0$.

But this seems quite strange, because it does not exploit any properties from the normal distribution except the fact that $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, which is the support of normal.

Am I being right?

Comment: What if $\Sigma$ is such that $X=Y$ with probability one.  It is possible for your polynomial $f(x,y)$ to be non trivial but $f(x,x)=0$ for all $x$...

Comment: @kimchilover you mean when $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & \sigma_1 \sigma_2  \\ \sigma_1 \sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2  \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Yes.  It's a "degenerate normal" but still normal.

Comment: @kimchilover I guess my reasoning is false when there is a dependency between $x$ and $y$. So is it true when $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, regardless of their distribution..?

Comment: Yes.  (Assuming a variance-zero rv does not count as a normal rv!)  And, as you pointed out, as long as $\mathbb R^2$ is the support of the rvs in question, its a no-brainer, not really  "about" the gaussian.